# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 124: www-browser: not found

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm configuring my new VPS to host a Rails application with Apache and Passenger.
I have an other VPS up and running, I configured months ago.

On the new one I installed Apache and its packages via `aptitude`, as I did on the first one.
Running the following command on the newest VPS returns a successful response

```
root@www:/etc/apache2# apache2ctl status
Apache Server Status for localhost

Server Version: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu)
Server Built: Jul 10 2009 18:47:48
...
```

The same command on the older VPS returns the following error

```
root@www:/etc/apache2# apache2ctl status
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 124: www-browser: not found
```

I don't have any kind of problem with Apache on this VPS, however I'd like to know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I should have found the solution.
Investigating the differences between the two servers, I found that the following command

/etc/alternatives/www-browser

in the older server returns

```
root@www:/etc/apache2# /etc/alternatives/www-browser
-su: /etc/alternatives/www-browser: No such file or directory
```

while on the younger

```
root@www:~$ /etc/alternatives/www-browser
w3m version w3m/0.5.1+cvs-1.968, options lang=en,m17n,image,color,ansi-color,mouse,gpm,menu,cookie,ssl,ssl-verify,external-uri-loader,w3mmailer,nntp,gopher,ipv6,alarm,mark,migemo
usage: w3m [options] [URL or filename]
```

The younger comes with `w3m` text browser installed.
In order to check the status, Apache needs a text browser to use.

Running the following command on the first server fixed the problem.

```
aptitude install w3m
```

Off course, `ELinks` or `lynx` whould be valid alternatives as well.

Answer (score 18):

As Phillippe said, install a command-line browser like `lynx`, `links`, or `elinks` to make this work.

The reason why it's happening is that the `apache2ctl status` command actually makes a request to the web server to check what's going on.  It works on the other VPS because that's got a command-line web browser already installed (probably pulled in as a dependency of another package).  I agree that the error message could be better, although if you examine the "Suggests" for the `apache2.2-common` package, `www-browser` is mentioned there.

Answer (score 4):

'www-browser' is the name of a virtual package. Try to install elinks (or links or lynx or whatever you prefer) by typing aptitude install elinks.

Answer (score 0):

try `ls -laF /etc/alternatives/www-browser` if the links points to non-existing file, remove it

then try to find some browser either `which links` or `which w3m` should work (if not, install it)

finally create a symbolic link to www-browser

```
ln -s /usr/bin/links /etc/alternatives/www-browser
```